# Apps written in web langs vs apps implemented natively

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Hi I am wanting to get into cross platform mobile app development. Can we go over the perks and cons of going with a native app or web app ?

The said cross platform mobile app would **require** a internet connection for it to run. Also can answers be based on:

- Memory usage (secondary and primary)
- run time speed, DB (SQL and NOSQL) access speed and support
- potential portability (if native ease of conversion)
- And finally last but not least, on the future "proof-ness" (direction
  of development and support)

Edit: this is a reworked question..

Comment: This is not a very good fit for a question on stackoverflow but it's an interesting question nonetheless. Mobile development best practices are always in flux, especially nowadays. If you need your app to be on the various stores, cordova and react native are popular choices. react native's approach sounds better overall (webviews still have performance issues on most mobiles) but it's also younger.

Comment: The question is not appropriate for SO. However having said that the same question still gets asked every day, so if you search you will find many many past questions with answers and comments regarding this.

Comment: If you know C# then take a look at xamarin

Comment: Would it be recommendable to make the "shells/bare bones" of the application in Java/Swift for their respective platforms, and then to use a Backend language to interact with them ? Thinking of Rails or PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i wanted to take the shortest time to get to the market i would go with HTML/CSS/JS, using a framework to ease the edge cases in various platforms, my preference in that scenario would be ionic. If and only if my app thrived would i turn it native, i would make sure that the investment of going native would be worth the return. But if i had some time and it was medium term project that i wanted to implement with the edgiest and best of both worlds, i would go with something like nativescript. But that's just me

Comment: Once you go with Ionic or some other framework like Xamarin, which seems most appealing right now. Like you mentioned for dev speed purposes. Why would I ever make the native app?

Comment: Most preferably to reduce the app size, reduce the memory footprint that comes with webview and make the app more performant at a lower cost on memory and user experience. Mostly just to make sure that the app doesn't frustrate users with weaker devices and ensure that anyone who wants the app doesn't have to worry about its tolls on the device.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll take that into consideration :)

Comment: Web apps are faster to do, that's true.

Answer (score -1):

For a mobile application you should make it with Java for Android and Swift for iOS. HTML5 apps have many problems such as low performances (have you seen the speed of JavaScript animations on mobile browsers ? If there are animations, of course, most time websites disable it because of bad performances).

Native apps are compiled (semi-compiled for Android) but JavaScript is an interpreted language and performances on mobile phones are bad. I think you should develop your app with a native language.

Comment: I don't say it's not possible to make web apps for Android or iOS ! I just say that performances are lower, especially when there are animations.

Comment: I see. My app would be more about providing a service/functionality. Not so much about animations. The only speed factor would be the retrial of GPS position and DB data.

Comment: Well, if it's just that, I think there's no problem to use a web app. The best way is to try and see ;)

Comment: Thanks man :) I may want to add more features but only if its not a flop :P

Answer (score -1):

## Vaadin TouchKit

If your app is a web app, if it requires an Internet connection and cannot work offline, and you want a mobile-like user interface, and you want to program in pure Java server-side but auto-magically render to the client in standard web technology without having to learn HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, WebSocket, Push, and so on, then check out [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com) and the add-on [TouchKit](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/touchkit).

[image]